Using cluster, the shorter regex pattern 'rt' matched but not longer 'rt0', 'rt2', 'rt4' pattern
This is crafting the syntax highlighting for Linux nftables (in Vimscript).
I need to be spreading multiple but simple regex patterns across groups within a cluster.  But I cannot make a simple OR-combo logic from separate group-names of regexes work together using a single syntax cluster:
hi lite        cluster_exthdr_expr Command
syntax cluster cluster_exthdr_expr
\ contains=
\    hbh_hdr_expr,  " has `hbh` but we ignore this in this SE/SO posting"
\    rt_hdr_expr,   " has `rt`  keyword + complex syntax"
\    rt0_hdr_expr,  " has `rt0` keyword + complex syntax"
\    rt2_hdr_expr,  " has `rt2` keyword + complex syntax"
\    rt4_hdr_expr,  " has `rt4` keyword + complex syntax"
   ...

The above syntax cluster always highlights the shorter rt keyword pattern but never the other longer rtX keywords. If I removed the shorter \ rt_hdr_expr, from \ contains=, then ALL the other longer rtX keywords get their highlighting restored and working again, but not the shorter rt.
syntax match rt0_hdr_expr "\vrt0" skipwhite contained
syntax match rt2_hdr_expr "\vrt2" skipwhite contained
syntax match rt4_hdr_expr "\vrt4" skipwhite contained
syntax match rt_hdr_expr "\vrt" skipwhite contained

EDIT: (was rt_hdr_expr firstly, but it was lastly in my vimscript file)
They are not the same as:
syntax match exthdr_expr "\v(rt0|r2|r4|rt)" skipwhite contained

The Gist
This syntax highlighting here is the actual work of Linux nftables, whose output from GNU bison utility generates the railroad diagrams. And in turn, I am translating the following railroad diagrams where I could NOT use a simple OR-combo regex ('\v(hbh|rt0|rt2|rt4|rt)'):
syntax match exthdr_expr "\v(rt0|r2|r4|rt)" skipwhite contained

due to additional sub-syntax logics following each of the rt, rt0, rt2, rt4 keywords.
Since there are additional identifiers/keyword/values following each of the rt keywords, all different, I can no longer use the simply syntax match "\v(rt0|rt2|rt4|rt) method, it is time to go the syntax cluster route (I think).
Details
The top-level RR diagram:

which I tried to translates into following Vimscript:
hi lite        cluster_exthdr_expr Command
syntax cluster cluster_exthdr_expr
\ contains=
\    hbh_hdr_expr,  " has `hbh` but we ignore this in this SE/SO posting"
\    rt_hdr_expr,   " has `rt`  keyword + complex syntax"
\    rt0_hdr_expr,  " has `rt0` keyword + complex syntax"
\    rt2_hdr_expr,  " has `rt2` keyword + complex syntax"
\    rt4_hdr_expr,  " has `rt4` keyword + complex syntax"
   ...

The above syntax cluster always highlights the shorter rt keyword pattern but never the other longer rtX keywords. If I removed the shorter \ rt_hdr_expr, from \ contains=, then the other longer rtX keywords get their highlighting restored and working again.
I'm quite sure this is a simple thing, but forgotten how to go about doing this correctly.
More on other <group-name>s:
The short RT (actual rt keyword) is:

represented by
syntax match rt_hdr_expr "\vrt" skipwhite contained

The longer RT0/RT2/RT4 (rt0, rt2, rt4) keywords are similarly shown as:

EDIT:
Added further patterns:

to assist the shorter rt diagram.
EDIT:

Re-order rts statements to reflect that rt came last in the vimscript file.


Do word boundaries help? For example rt\>?

Yes.... but I didn't use \> but using an additional pattern is required to assist with a shorter (rt) one to stand out from the rest of the similar pattern (rt0, rt2, rt4).  Whether \> works or not, gonna try it.  (I had to delve further into additional subsequential pattern to assist the shorter rt to break out, not ideal yet crude, but trying the \> approach.)

You must match also the next item or, at least, first few chars of it in order to resolve the conflict between rt, rt0, etc.
The extra match could be discarded then with the help of :h /\ze or :h :syn-pattern-offset or some other zero-length match.
Upd.

Any well-defined syntax is unambiguous. So there must be reason why rt0 + rt0field cannot be read as rt + 0..rt0field. Whether it's due to the fact that rt must also match word boundary, or be followed by non-digit, or something else I don't know. It's you who needs to re-read the syntax rules.

"Cluster" can be omitted. So instead of syn foo contains=@cluster_name it's often better to write simply syn foo contains=grp1,grp2,grp3 etc. Cluster is only good if you need to reference the same (lengthy) group set about 5-10 times.

Often syntax highlighters may be not as strict as true compilers. That is, I don't see too much shame in doing syn region foo start=/hbh/ start=/rt[024]\?/ end=/close_scope/ contains=hbh_hdr, rt_hdr,rt_hdr0,rt_hdr2,rt_hdr4 even though it doesn't really match original definition.

If several matches may match in the same position Vim prefers one that was defined later (:h syn-priority), not one of a greater length. This may be not the cleanest solution possible but it can be used to resolve the conflict as needed. However, your current code doesn't seem to respect that rule (rt defined before rt0 but still wins?), so I believe it's
not what you really have in your syntax file.


Upd. 2
Here is what I would try for a start
syn region exthdr start=/\<hbh\>/ end=/whatever/ contains=hbh_body contained
syn region exthdr start=/\<rt\>/ end=/whatever/ contains=rt_body contained
syn region exthdr start=/\<rt0\>/ end=/whatever/ contains=rt0_body contained
...


I do not think I can use \ze.   Regex is spread out over several Vimscript statements: syntax match rt_hdr_expr "\vrt" skipwhite contained, syntax match rt0_hdr_expr "\vrt0" skipwhite contained, syntax match rt2_hdr_expr "\vrt2" skipwhite contained, syntax match rt4_hdr_expr "\vrt4" skipwhite contained
They are not the same as:
syntax match exthdr_expr "\v(rt0|r2|r4|rt)" skipwhite contained

Do you meant to say use a pattern like syntax match rt_hdr_expr "\vrt\ze\s*" contained and not the syntax match rt_hdr_expr "\vrt" skipwhite contained?

I think Matt means you need to match (but discard) something following the rt to resolve ambiguities. I suggested word boundaries in the comments. Also, I believe you need the more Perl-like lookahead/behind constructs, as zs/ze don’t always work correctly in syntax constructs; I lost my reference, but zs/ze consume characters and prevent overlapping matches in ways that @<= don’t, for example.

it turns out that I did require to go deeper into rt_hdr_field to assist the shorter rt_hdr_expr pattern in breaking out uniquely enough from a larger group of same-patterns. (added rt_hdr_field to question above).

In syntax vimscript file, the ordering of syntax match rt[024] statements is rt0_hdr_expr, rt2_hdr_expr, rt4_hdr_expr, and then lastly its shorter variant of rt_hdr_field.

WAIT A GOL-DARN MOMENT!  Did you suggest syntax foo contains=..., where is the missing match, region, cluster, keyword?  Is that even an option?

The simplest fix I have is to insert a single whitespace ('\s') into the shorter `syntax match rt_hdr_expr "\vrt\s".  Doesn't seem right to me.

@JohnGreene No, it's not an option, of course. In real code one needs to specify match or region and also actual regex, etc.

Is it a bad thing that I use syntax cluster to keep closer to the naming as determined and given out by GNU Bison output that got derived from the nftables' parse-lexer.c?

It was #1.  I needed to shoehorn rt pattern alongside with rt0, rt2, rt4 into the regex: Easiest fix was to add a single whitespace to RT in form of "\vrt\s" regex;  #2: Cluster is my practice of using placeholders to mirror GNU Bison output (I have some 9,000 clusters left remaining to use); #3 is one good practical usage that I have been using; #4 is good to know. The statement orderings of syntax match matters. If you can polish #1, I'll accept this as an answer.
